# Spring @PreAuthorize hasAuthority Exception Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Boolean] for value 'hasAuthority

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, components, authorization

So I created a class with two simple public strings

```java
public final class Right {
    private Right() {
        super();
    }

    public static final String AUTH = "hasAuthority('admin') or hasAuthority('mod')";
}
```

When I used it together with the @PreAuthorize annotation at my controllers it works like a charm. I do not like that it is hardcoded. For this reason I've put the roles in the properties and I tried to use it as a component:

```java
@Component("authRule")
public class AuthRule {

    @Value("${role.administrator}")
    private String roleAdmin;

    @Value("${role.moderator}")
    private String roleMod;

    public String getRightAccess() {
        return "hasAuthority('" + roleAdmin+ "')" + " or hasAuthority('" + roleMod+ "')";
    }
}
```

When i use it in my PreAuthorize as :

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authRule.getRightAccess()")
```

I am getting back an exception of Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Boolean] for value 'hasAuthority('admin') or hasAuthority('mod')

if I hardcoded in the PreAuthorize. I am quite confused with this. Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick read of the documentation; https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-pre-post-annotations

It's likely that the value provided to the annotation is parsed only once. I think you need it to parse twice; once to trigger your custom component's method getRightAccess(). And a second time to parse the String result returned by that method. There are examples here if you do a general search for "Boolean"; https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

```
// evaluates to true
boolean isMember = parser.parseExpression("isMember('Mihajlo Pupin')").getValue(
        societyContext, Boolean.class);
```

So you probably need something like this in your getRightAccess() method;

```
return parser.parseExpression("hasAuthority('"+roleAdmin+"') or hasAuthority('"+roleMod+"')").getValue(Boolean.class);
```

Comment: @PreAuthorize takes a string value and uses the SPRING EL expression to convert it to a boolean value hasAuthority or hasRole are quite common with it. As I mentioned at the beginning of the post it works like a charm with the static Strings but not when I retrieve them from the properties.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. Sorry I can't be of more help, I've not used the Spring Security stuff before.

Comment: I used your new answer but it did not work as well. Nevertheless, it helped me delve into the SPEL parser and its solutions. I found out that I can pass any custom boolean value in the @PreAuthorize for this reason I created my own method and passed and it works. Sadly when We have to use the pre-defined ones such as hasAuthority you need a constant expression. But thank you again.

Comment: Where ```hasAuthority``` or ```hasRole``` method place?

Comment: try here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#:~:text=defaultRolePrefix%20on%20DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.-,hasAuthority,-(%5Bauthority%5D)